# why email sent by normal users but not sent by superusers?

Tags: django, sendmail

I need to use forgot password link to reset the password to a new one, the function works perfectly with me the problem is that: when I send the new request if that email was a superuser the request won't send, although, a normal user can send the request except the superuser so, anyone can help me in that?

```
def password_reset_request(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        password_reset_form = PasswordResetForm(request.POST)

        if password_reset_form.is_valid():
            data = password_reset_form.cleaned_data['email']
            associated_users = User.objects.filter(email=data)
            try:
                usr = User.objects.get(email=data)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                messages.error(request, "%s Does not exists" % data, extra_tags='user_error')
                return redirect('accounts:reset_password')
            if associated_users.exists():
                for user in associated_users:
                    subject = "Password Reset Requested"
                    plaintext = template.loader.get_template('accounts/password_reset_subject.txt')
                    htmltemp = template.loader.get_template('accounts/password_reset_email.html')
                    c = {
                    "email": user.email,
                    'domain': '127.0.0.1:8000',
                    'site_name': 'Website',
                    "uid": urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                    "user": user,
                    'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user),
                    'protocol': 'http',
                    }
                    text_content = plaintext.render(c)
                    html_content = htmltemp.render(c)
                    try:
                        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [user.email], headers={'Reply-To': 'admin@example.com'})
                        msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
                        msg.send()
                    except BadHeaderError:
                        return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
                    messages.info(request, "Password reset instructions have been sent to the email address entered.")
                return redirect("accounts:password_reset_done")
    password_reset_form = PasswordResetForm(None)
    return render(request=request, template_name="accounts/password_reset_form.html", context={"form": password_reset_form})
```

Comment: Use the builtin [`PasswordResetView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView) instead of writing this yourself. Also `messages.error(request, "%s Does not exists" % data, extra_tags='user_error')` **don't do this** that is a security vulnerability and allows people to find out that some email is registered with your website. You should instead simply state that the email was sent with a potential email being sent to the email address that some one tried to do this etc.

Comment: but the code works fine it just not work with the superuser only, for the message where is the vulnerability here I didn't understand! it's just a message if this user doesn't exist will display could you explain more, please?